# Test Cafe: ERROR Cannot find the browser. "/bin/sh" is neither a known browser alias, nor a path to an executable file

Tags: testcafe

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe

USER root

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY tests/TestCafe tests/TestCafe

WORKDIR tests/TestCafe

CMD /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage index.js > /home/output.txt
```

> ERROR Cannot find the browser. "/bin/sh" is neither a known browser alias, nor a path to an executable file.
>
> Type "testcafe -h" for help.

Comment: For some reason, `bin/sh` was passed as a browser argument to TestCafe. From your example, it is not completely clear why this happened.
The only thing you can do is to add some console.log statements to the argument parsing mechanism here: node_modules/testcafe/lib/cli/argument-parser/index.ts (the `parse` method)